# drop certain columns from a dataframe while converting to list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a sample dataframe:

```
    Id    Age  Name
0   0110  23   Max
1   2009  56   Stan
2   1167  25   Joy
3   8878  44   Lee
```

at present for the input dataframe I'm using

```
dfnew = df.drop(df.columns.difference(['Id']),1)
```

to drop unwanted column(i.e Id) in dataframe and proceeding ahead. Which is correct but there are two dataframes.

is there anyway we can optimise it?

**while converting the dataframe to a list can we have only age and name in the list and ignore Id like
lst = [[23,Max],[56,stan]....]**

please assist on this. Thank you.

Comment: `df[["Age", "Name"]].apply(list, axis=1).tolist()` OR `df.drop("Id", axis=1).apply(list, axis=1).tolist()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `drop` the unwanted column, convert to a numpy array and convert to list. This is faster than `apply(list, axis=1)`.

```
lst = df.drop(columns='Id').to_numpy().tolist()
```

Output:

```
[[23, 'Max'], [56, 'Stan'], [25, 'Joy'], [44, 'Lee']]
```